# How can I wrap text in a row to avoid cropping in Python's FPDF library?

Tags: python, web, fpdf

So I am stuck at multiple points but I am kind of scared to post multiple posts at the same time so I will start with this one. I need this code to look for the longest string in a row and just like in excel - wrap text. now if the text is longer than the row, it will crop out and it would look like a mess. Chat GPT unfortunately is not helping, here's the code :)

P.S. I am using Python FPDF

I tried chat GPT and some random stuff that came into my mind.

```
def PDF_dokuments_skolas():
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM jasanasskolas")
result = cursor.fetchall()

pdf = FPDF(orientation='L')
pdf.add_page()

page_width = pdf.w - 2 * pdf.l_margin

pdf.add_font('Arial', '', 'backend/arialuni.ttf', uni=True)

pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 14.0)
pdf.cell(page_width, 0.0, 'Skolu dati', align='C')
pdf.ln(10)

pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 12)

col_width = page_width / 6

pdf.ln(1)

th = pdf.font_size

for row in result:
    pdf.cell(col_width, th, str(row['ID']), border=1)
    pdf.cell(col_width, th, row['nosaukums'], border=1)
    pdf.cell(col_width, th, row['atrasanasvieta'], border=1)
    pdf.cell(col_width, th, row['darbalaiks'], border=1)
    pdf.cell(col_width, th, row['WEBadrese'], border=1)
    pdf.cell(col_width, th, row['telefonanumurs'], border=1)
    pdf.ln(th)

pdf.ln(10)

pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 10.0)
pdf.cell(page_width, 0.0, '- end of report -', align='C')

return Response(
    pdf.output(dest='S'),
    mimetype='application/pdf',
    headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=skolas.pdf'}
)
```